# Draw circle in TikZ by specifying endpoint and distances instead of angles and radius

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

In the classical `arc` command in TikZ, we specify an endpoint of the arc, followed by the initial and final angles, and finally the radius.

I would like to create a macro (if it doesn't already exist) that instead
of specifying the angles and radius, specifies two distances, one horizontal and one
vertical as shown below :

[image]

Note that this command is less powerful than the usual `arc` command as it
only draws arcs that are symmetric with respect to some vertical axis.
The conversion formulas are as follows : the radius is $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2b}$
and the initial angle is $cos^{-1}(\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2})$.

Here is my failed attempt to implement this with `tikzset` (in the
test file below, the two tikzpictures should be identical) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    afro/.style args={#1:#2}{
        insert path={ arc(acos((2*#1*#2)/(#1*#1+#2*#2)):180-acos((2*#1*#2)/(#1*#1+#2*#2)):((#1*#1+#2*#2)/(2*#1*#2)))}
    }
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[green] (0,0) arc (37:143:2.5cm);
\draw (0,0) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) afro (2cm:1cm);
\draw (0,0) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Perhaps I should use pgfkeys ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are doing three essential things wrong with your `afro` style: 1. It is a style, it need to be applied inside `[` and `]`; 2. You declare `#1:#2` but use `(#1:#2)`; 3. You did not protect the parenthesis. You will need to do `arc({acos(…)}:{180-acos(…)}:{((…))})` and `\draw[red] (0,0) [afro=2cm:1cm]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas.

The `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared` test can be done after a `\pgfmathparse` operation (which `\pgfmathsetmacro` uses).
The test will be true when at any place inside the mathematical evaluation something with a dimension has been used (either a TeX dimen or simply a statement like `2cm`).
If a unit is used either in `#1` (a) or `#2` (b) it is assumed that you want to draw your arc in the canvas coordinate system, otherwise in the local coordinate system. (Cf. `(1, 2)` vs `(1cm, 2cm)`)

The calculation for the angle is also done before as it is used twice.

The `/utils/exec` key does nothing special, it justs executes the given code (like `\pgfextra` basically).

---

Note that the `arc (…)` path operator is deprecated.
It is better to use the `arc […]` path operator, that way you can declare various options in an outer scope or use it in the `every arc` style.

---

More magic is needed if you want to use something like `arc[a=2, b=1]` without the auxiliary `chord do` style.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  chord/.style args={#1:#2}{
    /utils/exec=%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\myTempVal{(#1)*(#1)/(#2)/2+(#2)/2}%
      \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared\edef\myTempVal{\myTempVal pt}\fi
      \pgfmathsetmacro\myTempAng{acos(2*(#1)*(#2)/((#1)*(#1)+(#2)*(#2)))},
    radius=\myTempVal, start angle=\myTempAng, end angle=180-\myTempAng},
  afro/.style={insert path={arc[chord={#1}]}},
  chord a/.initial=, chord b/.initial=,
  chord do/.style={chord={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/chord a}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/chord b}}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[green] (0,0) arc (37:143:2.5cm);
\draw (0,0) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) [afro=2cm:1cm];
\draw (0,0) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] (0,0) arc [chord=2:1];
\draw (0,0) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[chord b=1]
\foreach \a in {.1, .2, ..., 2}
  \draw[black] (0,0) arc [chord a=\a, chord do];
\draw (0,0) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is also the `math` library where you can write something like `\myRadius = <calculation>;` but I don't think the `unitsdeclared` hook can be used properly.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is possible to let the `calc` library do most of the work. Then parameters can be given with or without dimensions:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{afro/.style args={(#1:#2)}{
  insert path={
    coordinate (@1)
    ($(@1)+(#1,#2)$) coordinate (@2)
    let \p1=($(@2)-(@1)$),
        \n1={(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)/(2*\y1)},
        \n2={acos((2*\x1*\y1)/(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1))} in
    ($(@1)+(#1,0)$) arc (\n2:180-\n2:\n1)
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) [afro=(2cm:1)];
\draw [red, ->] (0,0) -- (2cm,0);
\draw [red, ->] (0,0) -- (0,1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem is doing math with distances.  pgfmath uses 1=1pt to do calculations, while tikz typically uses 1=1cm when graphing.  It has the ability to add units to `\pgfmathresult`, but all it does is take the first unit found while parsing.

This is a macro solution.  You might be able to do this using a code key, if you are more comfortable with keys than macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{calc}% not needed inside tikz

\newcommand{\afro}[2]% #1 = a, #2 = b
 {\pgfextra{% needed inside a path
    \pgfmathparse{#1/1cm}%
    \let\a=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{#2/1cm}%
    \let\b=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{0.5*(\a*\a/\b + \b)}%
    \let\r=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{acos(\a/\r)}%
    \let\angle=\pgfmathresult}%
  arc(\angle:180-\angle:\r cm)%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[green] (0,0) arc (37:143:2.5cm);
\draw (0,0) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) \afro{2cm}{1cm};
\draw (0,0) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. What I don't like about this solution is that the units are not specified in `\afro{2}{1}`. Is there a way to modify your solution so that `\afro{2cm}{1cm}` and `\afro{2pt}{1pt}` will each be interpreted the right way ?

Comment: Yes.  It is even possible to have it work both ways, but the code is tricky.  See page 925 (section 89.1.2).

Comment: Page 925 of which book ? I only know the LaTeX companion

Comment: The tikz/pgf manual.  You can download it from CTAN, but you probably already have a copy.  Mine is in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\generic\pgf

Comment: I created a folder that contains nothing but shortcuts to various LaTeX manual, plus a few files like source2e.pdf and symbols-a4.pdf.